# Prove that the operator $Tv = (v_2,\frac{1}{2} v_1) $ is a contraction

Tags: fixed-points, contraction-operator

Consider the complete metric space $(R^2,d_2) $ where $d_2$ is the Euclidean distance. I have to check whether the following operator $T:R^2 \rightarrow R^2$ is a contraction:

$ T(v) = (v_2,\frac{1}{2}v_1) $ for any $v=(v_1,v_2) \in R^2$

What this does is to flip the coordinates of a vector and cut by half the second.

This is the definition of a contraction: there exists some $\beta \in [0,1)$ such that

$ d(Tv,Tw) \leq \beta d(v,w)$ for all $v,w \in R^2$

First of all, I found that this mapping has a fixed point: $ v^\star = (0,0)$ but that's not the point of the exercise. I tried to apply the definition of contraction. Take two arbitrary vectors $v=(v_1,v_2)$, $w=(w_1,w_2)$, then $T(v)=(v_2,\frac{1}{2}v_1)$ and $T(w)=(w_2,\frac{1}{2}w_1)$. I have

$ d(Tv,Tw) = (v_2-w_2)^2+(\frac{1}{2}v_1-\frac{1}{2}w_1)^2 = (v_2-w_2)^2+\frac{1}{4}(v_1-w_1)^2 < (v_2-w_2)^2+(v_1-w_1)^2 = d(v,w)$

so I managed to show only that $ d(Tv,Tw) < d(v,w)$ which is the definition of weak contraction. And by the way this is not enough to invoke the contraction mapping theorem... So I'm a bit puzzled. Is this mapping a contraction or not? Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What if $v_1 = w_1$?

Comment: $T$ is not a (strict) contraction.

Comment: Why do they call it a contraction? It is very confusing in context of tensors.

Answer (score 1):

Your function $T$ is linear, so the condition is equivalent to showing $\|Tv\| \leq  c\|v\|$ with $c < 1$ for all $v$. From here, we can see that $T$ cannot be a contraction: take for example $e_2$, which verifies $Te_2 = e_1$ and so $\|Te_2\| = \|e_1\|$.

Comment: I think $T e_2 = e_1$ but apart from this your example goes through. Thanks!

Comment: @Alessandro my bad, you're correct. Glad I could help :)

Comment: @Alessandro Yep it is the special case which makes it not work. But all other linear combinations it should work.